# record, and replay rabbitmq data

Tags: rabbitmq

Is there a rabbit mq plugin or application that can subscribe to rabbit mq messages, save them to disk, and then publish the messages back at the same rate that they came in?

I am just starting with rabbitmq and trying to figure out the best way to set up integration tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to fanout your messages to 2 separate queues ? If so, create two queues and bind them to a fanout exchange. All the messages published to the exchange will be replicated. You can then configure 1 of the 2 queues to save the messages to disk !